# Is there any way to implement list of different links in Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a blog page where my requirement is to list a group od links in a html page.

`app.py`:

```
@app.route("/blog")
def blog():
    return render_template('blog.html')
```

`blog.html`:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/templates/chapter 1.html">Chapter 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/templates/chapter 2.html">Chapter 2</a>
    </li>
<ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

Stored all my html pages in `templates` directory.

I am able to open the `localhost:8000/blog` where I can view all the `Chapter1`, `chapter2` links, but when I click on the link I get error:

```
http://localhost:5000/templates/chapter%201.html

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

[image: error traceback]

I am sure that this will not work as it is pointing to different URL, can some one guide how do I implement the list of Chapter in Flask app?

Comment: I don't understand why you have done this. Why would you think that you could link directly to templates?

Comment: i was thinking there would be a way directly where i can hookup static pages , inside the blog page, by calling the blog function in app. Can you suggest me how this can be done, i have pasted the image in here.

Comment: will there be any other way to do this

Answer (score 1):

If you had the static html files already, you should serve it as static file as mentioned in [document here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files). Then, put urls for these files in your main page:

```
url_for('static', filename='chapter1.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `templates` directory is not linked to a URL, the files in that directory are not 'published'. You shouldn't put files there you intent to serve without processing (executing the templates).

With the default configuration only files in the `static` directory are accessible via the `/static/` URL path prefix, see the [*Static Files* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files) of the Flask Quickstart.

The intent for the `templates` directory is for the files to be loadable as Jinja2 templates using the [`render_template()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates), where you use that function in endpoint functions you registered with Flask for specific URLs.

You may want to try out the [Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/) first, it covers both [templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/templates/) and [static files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/) in more detail.

For a blog site, the normal pattern would be for you to store the blog post data in a database or text files in some way Python can easily load, then use a *single* template to render the contents. You'd register a URL with a pattern, which would call a function that can load any blog page data, then use the blog page template to render the output:

```
@app.route('/blog/<page_name>')
def blog_page(page_name):
    page_data = load_blog_page(page_name)
    if not page_data:  # no page? Produce a not found error.
        abort(404)
    return render_template('blog_page.html', **page_data)
```

The above function will be called when a browser visits URLs that start with `/blog/`, and is called with the next part as the `page_name` variable; e.g. `/blog/chapter-1` would result in `page_name` being set to `'chapter-1'`. Note that URLs can't have spaces in them (spaces would have to be encoded to `%20` for the URL to still be a URL).

The function then loads the page data (with a `load_log_page()` function you'd have to write yourself), then provided `page_data` is not empty or `None` or some other false-y value indicating that the page doesn't actually exist, uses the `render_template()` function to produce HTML output. `render_template()` will use the file `templates/blog_page.html` as the template file here, and `page_data` is assumed to be a dictionary whose key-value pairs make the variables the template can use.